# editor text cut off when using 2 spaces (after periods)

Tags: tinymce

I have noticed that my TinyMCE editor in Wordpress MU 2.9.2 loses text after a double space when you save a blog post.  This is a problem because some users habitually use two spaces after a period.

In these two examples, there are two spaces between "test" and "test":

- "test  test" ("test__test") becomes "test" when the blog is saved
- "test  test, the rest of my long blog post" ("test__test,_the_rest_of_my_long_blog_post") becomes "test" when the blog is saved

***Edit***:

I updated to WP 3.2.1 and can confirm that this is still an issue.

Comment: First: Update (for **lot's** of reasons).

Comment: Please update or confirm that you can reproduce this on latest WP version. Otherwise this would be somewhat moot.

Comment: Question edited... though if there is no simple fix, or am I further convinced to, I will try updating WP

Comment: I updated to 3.2.1 and confirm that this is still an issue

Comment: @SomewhereThere - this is not normal behavior, try disabling plugins and switching to default theme to determine what's causing this.

Comment: still seeing the behavior with plugins disabled and default theme enabled... I noticed that this only occurs when posting on MU blogs, and not on the backend to the main site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:

In 2.9.2 under "New Blog Defaults", the field "Encoding for pages and feeds" was blank and should have been `UTF-8`.  When I updated this field on all blogs, the problem went away.

In 3.2.1 you can edit this value on a blog by blog basis on the reading settings page: `/wp-admin/options-reading.php`.  I'm not sure what the default value for new blogs in 3.2.1 is, or if there is somewhere to change the default, but I'm guessing it is `UTF-8`

Comment: could you please explain where you find "New Blog Defaults" .... it seems that I also need to set my UTF to 8 but I don't know how or where.

Comment: see my edits above